# CORS Preflight check error google cloud (firebase) python function reactjs

Tags: python, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

edit: This fetch needs and authorization which I've gotten to work. Only issue remaining is CORS ... I've tried to set up wildcard config, which didn't work. Right now, the error code I get is `preflight response not successful 403`. This leads me to believe that there are two possibilities.

1. CORS error is a mask for something else thanks to the people in the comments. Whenever I deploy my cloud function, I see memory limit of 256Mi exceeded error in the google cloud logs. How can I reduce this?
   What I'm thinking: 2. This is a CORS issue, then how do I correctly handle the preflight response in my flask app/google cloud function. I realised I can't pass the preflight response check since it sends it without an auth header. **So to bypass this I need my function to be on the same domain as my front-end.** Seems easy enough, but can't get it to work ...
   firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/functionName",
        "function": "functionName"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "name": "functionName"
    }
  ]
}
```

————————
Error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example-uc.a.run.app/' from origin 'https://example.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> I'm using a create-react-app hosted on firebase as my front-end and hosted my back-end on firebase functions in python.
> here's my fetch from the front-end side

```
const sendMessage = async () => {
    try {
        ...
        const response = await fetch('https://example-uc.a.run.app', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ user_input: userInput }),
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending message:', error);
    }
};
```

here are parts of my main.py:

```
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
from firebase_functions import https_fn, options
from flask import Flask, jsonify
initialize_app()
app = Flask(__name__)
@https_fn.on_request(
    cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins=["https://example.web.app"],
        cors_methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    )
)
def chat(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.web.app',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    }
    if req.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return ('', 204, headers)
    ...
   
    return (jsonify(response_data), 200, headers)
```

I've tried handling it with chatGPT for 4 hours but won't resolve this at all. tried all sorts of solutions ranging in how explicit they are. I'm probably misunderstanding something basic and overlooking an easy solution. Please help.
Tried using CORS(app)
tried setting up the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *
tried passing recourses in the CORS arguments: CORS(app, resources={r"/": {"origins": "https://example.web.app"}})
if I remove the header in my fetch then I get CORS error 403
nothing solved the CORS policy error from appearing which prohibits me from fetching from my own back-end.
I stil want this to be secure and not ditch all security measures.
also if someone sees security issues in the way I'm doing this right now, please help me if I need to add some auth in the fetch or something.

Comment: 1) Is your function anonymous or requires authorization? 2) Review the HTTP request headers and make sure your CORS configuration is allowing those headers. 3) I start with a wildcard CORS configuration allowing all origins, all methods, all headers, etc. which is basically disabling CORS. Once that is working, I fine-tune the CORS configuration. 4) Tip: until you know how to write and deploy software, stay away from ChatGPT. Once ChatGPT can actually solve your problem, you will no longer be needed. In other words, you are helping ChatGPT replace you while making your job harder today.

Comment: @JohnHanley _[...] allowing all origins, all methods, all headers, etc. which is basically disabling CORS._ Not disabling CORS, but the SOP. Couldn't agree more about being wary of ChatGPT's advice, though.

Comment: This is an interesting article on CORS: https://medium.com/datamindedbe/cors-and-the-sop-explained-f59de3a5078

Comment: @FelixT Have you sanity checked that you can call the Cloud Function directly from both your browser and a tool like Postman or cURL? Do the Cloud Functions logs show anything abnormal? It's worth checking this as sometimes a CORS error masks a deployment error such as a failed deployment, missing dependency, null reference exception, and so on.

Comment: @JohnHanley instead of returning the const headers I now return "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and it still returns the same errors. Also replaced my headers to {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"} and still same errors. error is the preflight req.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the article. I'm still not passing the preflight check ... Also, didn't want to expose the url since I don't want people to be able to call it. It would cost a shit ton otherwise to me.

Comment: @samthecodingman when looking at the google cloud logs I see `ERROR 'Memory limit of 256 MiB exceeded with 320 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory'
`

Comment: @JohnHanley also in the google cloud console logs I see this: `"The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"`

Comment: @FelixT That unauthenticated invocations error is one of the deployment errors I was talking about. When a Firebase Function is deployed from the CLI, it is meant to grant `allUsers` the permission to invoke the function. This does not seem to have occurred during your deployment. You will either need to [reconfigure it from the GCloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment) or delete and redeploy the function.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thanks, isn't that unsafe? can't everyone then access my function? Is there a way for me to authenticate myself when calling it? Apologies for my ignorance, please be patient with me.

Comment: The first question I asked you in my first comment was about authorization.

Comment: @JohnHanley apparently it requires auth. so I need to add it in the request header, I have no idea which token to put there. Please be patient with me, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: When you are asked questions, those are tips for more information to include in your post. Review the comments and then update your post with the information we require to help you. Try to not use the comments as a chat feature as most people will not read them to figure out your problem. Put everything in your post.

Comment: @JohnHanley great thank you! I did it. I’ve tried adding multiple tokens/keys during testing to check which one would work. But the request won’t get authenticated. Can you please tell me which token it requires?

Comment: Cloud Functions requires an OIDC Identity Token. Firebase SDKs include methods to generate that token for you. Note: you are now missing two major problems. Functions authorization and CORS. Work on one problem at a time. Also, you must understand how authentication and authorization is implemented. Review this for Functions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Comment: @JohnHanley CORS fixed, I got it on the same domain to pass the preflight check, can you please help me with the auth now. should I create a login function with firebase and get the token that way somehow? check my updated question for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS SOLVED: There were different parts at play here.

I'm using firebase for everything here. I did not pass the preflight check since I was using the url firebase gave me on my front-end. And the preflight check doesn't send the any headers to the backend, so no auth.  I changed my firebase json to rewrite everything of `/functionName` to the correct function.

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/functionName",
        "function": "functionName"
      }
    ]

  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "name": "functionName"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I had auth issues as well ...

To fix that temporarily, I followed [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token)

**Don't know how to make this for production environment though ...**
here's my front-end call:

```
const response = await axios.post(
            '/functionName',
            { user_input: userInput },
            {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${identityToken}`,
              },
            }
          );
```

and my main.py:

```
@https_fn.on_request()
def chat(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    if req.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.web.app',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type', 
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)
    headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.web.app',
        }

    try:  

        response_data = {...}

        return (jsonify(response_data), 200, headers)
    except:
        return ("Something went wrong processing", 400, headers)
    finally: 
        print('everything went great')
```